# Is there a notion of a higher Kullback-Leibler divergence?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, st.statistics

For discrete probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ defined on the same sample space, $\mathcal{X}$, the Kullback-Leibler divergence is defined as
$$
D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \parallel Q)=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P(x) \log \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}
$$

Is there a notion of a higher Kullback-Leibler divergence? In other words, has the following divergence been studied:

$$
D^k_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \parallel Q)=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P(x) \left(\log \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)^k.
$$

This is with a view to generalizing Stam's inequality.

Comment: What is raised here to the $k$th power, the fraction or the log?

Comment: @IosifPinelis- The log. Thanks for pointing the typo out, I have now edited the question

Comment: Possibly useful: https://mathoverflow.net/q/210469/121692

Comment: @πr8 along those lines the term "varentropy" may be useful, see for example [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04093).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be interested in the notion of [renyi divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#R%C3%A9nyi_divergence). There have been generalizations of Stam's inequality to this setting, see [Variants of the Entropy Power Inequality by Bobkov and Marsiglietti](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8076873).

Note that this is not for your proposed variant of the KL divergence. A common way to generalizing ways of measuring distances between two distributions is via [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence).
These satisfy many useful properties that things like the KL divergence (for example, the data-processing inequality).

Your formula may be written as an $f$-divergence for $f_k(x) = x(\ln x)^k$.
All the literature on $f$-divergences I know of assumes that $f(x)$ is convex (it is quite key to the theory), but while $f_1$ is convex (e.g. viewing the KL divergence as an $f$-divergence fits into the existing theory well, which is of course by design), $f_k$ need not be convex for $k>1$ (and one can check that $f_2$ is already non-convex), so your proposed generalization is in a technical sense quite different than the KL divergence.